# How do I force a browser to render a file XHTML5, the XML serialization of HTML5?

Tags: xml, xhtml, mime-types, chromium, html

Is there anyway to force a browser to render XHTML5, the XML serialization of HTML5? Obviously, you can do it with server-side control of the mime-type, but is there a supported way to invoke the XML serialization using a file?

A test of this would be rendering `&nbsp;` recent versions of Chromium will actually halt rendering if they encounter this element. How do I invoke this same behavior by opening an invalid XHTML5 document.

Comment: To create a test for [jwysiwyg](http://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg) editor for XHTML5 documents..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there a supported way to invoke the XML serialization using a file?

If you mean "when loading from the local filesystem" then just give the file a .xhtml file extension.

> A test of this would be rendering `&nbsp;` recent versions of Chromium will actually halt rendering if they encounter this element.

That isn't a very good test. It just means that the parser is a generic XML parser rather than one that is XHTML 5 aware. The [specification says using them is 'unsafe'](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax) not 'forbidden'.

> According to the XML specification, XML processors are not guaranteed to process the external DTD subset referenced in the DOCTYPE. This means, for example, that using entity references for characters in XHTML documents is unsafe if they are defined in an external file (except for <, >, &, " and ').

If you want to do a proper test, then make the document non-well-formed. e.g. by leaving off the end tag for a paragraph (which is allowed in HTML but not in XHTML).

Comment: What browser does this work in. This triggers the XML processor in Firefox, but it refuses to do anything but render the documented as unstyled XML generating *This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.*, Chromium does the same *This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.*

Comment: That usually means you have failed to specify the namespace with the xmlns attribute on the root element `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">`

Comment: That's the XHTML1.0 namespace.. (Just go to the url and look http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml). There isn't a namespace or DTD for HTML5 -- it isn't even a proper subset of SGML.

Comment: That's the XHTML namespace — it isn't versioned, and it isn't a URI (it just happens to look like one to help ensure uniqueness). The document at the matching URI specifically says it is for, among other things, "HTML 5: A vocabulary and associated APIs for HTML and XHTML". HTML5 doesn't have a DTD or namespace and the HTML serialisation isn't a subset (or application) of SGML, but the question is about the XHTML serialisation, which does have a namespace and **is** an XML application.

Comment: Cool beans, so that seems to be it. XML provides `xmlns` -- HTML5 lacking a DTD can't deny that. That provides the styling information (though I'd be interested to know *how* it does that if it is unversioned). The `.xhtml` or `\.x.*` extension throws the browsers into XML parsing mode. Nifty. You++ Thanks for helping me clear up the differences between not having a style sheet, and not having a DTD.

Comment: The namespace doesn't provide styling information. It just tells the browser that `<p>` (for example) is "p from the XHTML namespace" instead of "p from some other namespace". The browser knows, internally, how to render a "p from the XHTML namespace".

Answer (score -1):

`&nbsp;` is a valid [named character reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#named-character-references) in (X)HTML5

**Update**: Oops, that sections only applies to the HTML serialisation, so it's not relevant.

Comment: That isn't true. There are no DTDs permitted in HTML5, so XHTML5 is left without these named references (it can not pull in DTD to define them). *"According to the XML specification, XML processors are not guaranteed to process the external DTD subset referenced in the DOCTYPE. This means, for example, that using entity references for characters in XHTML documents is unsafe if they are defined in an external file (except for &lt;, &gt;, &amp;, &quot; and &apos;)."* [source](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax)

Comment: @Evan Carroll, My statement is wrong, but not because of DTDs. It was wrong because the part I quoted dealt exclusively with the HTML serialisation.

Comment: @Evan Carroll, I actually found that out before I saw your mention. I also believe I have a better answer for you now, but I gotta leave  for a bit. I'll post a new answer later.